# Web socket in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, sockets, angular

I created a windows service that is hosting WCF web service on port 3000 and web socket on port 8800. The site using these services is also hosted on the port 3000. The communication between the site and the WCF web services works very fine and I'm able to call them.

However, the site is developped with angular2 and I'm using "socket.io-client" to connect to the web socket (implemented using websocket-sharp) and when I do this, I get:

> GET
>   http://dev-sp-build.sfpd.fgov.be:8800/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LeEF_1J
>   501 (Not Implemented)

Suivi de

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://dev-sp-build.sfpd.fgov.be:8800/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LeEG3vq. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://dev-sp-build.sfpd.fgov.be:3000' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

The second error seems to indicate an issue with CORS. However, I have no idea how to define the correct header as the web socket is hosted in a Windows Service.

The first error is also quite weird, I don't get why I get a "501 Not implemented". It looks like a .NET error in a virtual method that should be overriden but I checked the documentation of "websocket-sharp" and didn't find anything about that...